# How to get previous Six months into an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use moment to get the previous six months, using the below code.

```
ngOnInit(){
let mom: moment.Moment;
var d = new Date();
let numberOfMonths=6;
let previousSIxMonths:string[]=[];

while (this.numberOfMonths > 0) {
  this.previousSixMonths.push(mom.subtract(this.numberOfMonths, 'months').format('MMMM'));

  this.numberOfMonths--;
  console.log(this.numberOfMonths);
}
console.log(this.previousSixMonths);
}
```

However these cards should be displayed whenever I am on the page, and hence I have written the above code inside `OnInit`. Once I have all the past six months in the array, the idea is to loop over the array and display in cards. But the doesn't really work for me.

I want all my previous six months to be in an array so that I could loop across the array.

Considering this is October month, the expected output should be:

```
["Oct","Sept","Aug","July","June","May"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to do what you're needing:

```
var previousSixMonths = function(){
  let n = 0;
  let arRet = [];
  
  for(; n < 6; n++)
    arRet.push(moment().subtract(n, 'months').format('MMMM'));
  return(arRet)
}();

console.log(previousSixMonths);
```